# How to show that $1/\cosh(x) < \sinh(x)/x < x/\sinh(x)$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I was going through an old exam paper and I saw this question.

How to show that for $0 < x < \pi/2$, $$\frac{1}{\cosh(x)} < \frac{\sin(x)}{x} < \frac{x}{\sinh(x)}\;?$$

I can see numerically that it is true but how can one prove it?

Comment: Try treating the inequalities separately. If you get rid of denominators in the first one, a trig identity involving $\cosh(x)\sinh(x)$ should help you, and for the second inequality: when, more generally, is $\frac{x}{y} < \frac{y}{x}$ true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin with
$$f(x):=\sin x\cosh x-x\ .$$
One computes
$$f'(x)=\cos x\cosh x+\sin x\sinh x-1$$
and $$f''(x)=2\cos x\sinh x>0\qquad\left(0<x<{\pi\over2}\right)\ .$$
As $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ this immediately implies $f(x)>0$ for $0<x<{\pi\over2}$, and this allows to conclude the first of the stated inequalities.

For the second inequality we begin with
$$g(x):=x^2-\sin x \sinh x\ .$$
One computes
$$g'(x)=2x-\cos x\sinh x-\sin x\cosh x$$
and then
$$g''(x)=2(1-\cos x\cosh x)\ .$$
In a moment we shall prove that
$$\cos x\cosh x<1\qquad\left(0<x<{\pi\over2}\right)\ .\tag{1}$$
Since $g(0)=g'(0)=0$ we can  conclude that $g(x)>0$ for $0<x<{\pi\over2}$, and this settles the second of the stated inequalities.
For a proof of $(1)$ we note without proof that
$$0<\tanh t<\tan t\qquad\left(0<t<{\pi\over2}\right)\ .$$
Integrating this from $t=0$ to $t=x$ gives
$$\log(\cosh x) <-\log(\cos x)\qquad\left(0<x<{\pi\over2}\right)\ ,$$
which is equivalent to $(1)$.

Comment: This is very nice and clean. Thank you.